# Hibernate updates persistent object even if validation fails with Hibernate Validator

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation

I'm using Hibernate Validator in a Spring MVC app. 
I configured it in context.xml

`<bean id="validator" class="com.mycompany.appname.validation.Validator" />`

Now I use it in my controllers to validate different objects.
That's ok with transient objects, but how about persistent objects? For e.x:

I load one:

```
MyObject o = myDao.getById(someId);
o.setName(name);
o.setPhone(phone);
Set<ConstraintViolation<o>> violations= validator.validate(o);
```

Hibernate updates it even if validation fails for this object!

I tried to annotate `validate()` method of `Validator` with

```
@PrePersist
@PreUpdate
@PreRemove
public <RT> Set<ConstraintViolation<RT>> validate(RT target){...}
```

But still it updates no matter if validation failed or not.
I do not want to throw exception if validation fails though.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Hibernate to perform validation before update automatically, see [7.3. ORM integration](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-integration.html#validator-checkconstraints-orm). Perhaps it's the best choice if you don't want to perform specific actions in case of validation failure.

Alternatively, if you want to initiate validation manually as you currenly do, it's up to you to decide what to do with object that caused validation failure.

For example, you can throw an exception to trigger rollback of the current transaction (if you use Spring transaction management), so that changes you made won't be saved to the database.

If you don't want to roll back the transaction, you can remove entity from the session by calling `Session.evict()` in order to prevent invalid state from saving:

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Merchant>> violations= validator.validate(o); 
if (!violations.isEmpty()) myDao.doNotUpdate(o);
```

.

```
public void doNotUpdate(MyObject o) {
    sf.getCurrentSession().evict(o);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I was aware of the session evict and rollback feature. I want the automatic checking of hibernate as well as manual in spring controllers, as I want to notify the end user for invalid input.